# Javascript / jQuery - Reorder divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, dataset

given this code:

```
<div class="row" data-status="1">A</div>
<div class="row" data-status="0">B</div>
<div class="row" data-status="1">C</div>
<div class="row" data-status="0">D</div>
```

I want to reorder the div elements in the DOM and push the ones with `data-status="1"` to the top, like this:

```
<div class="row" data-status="1">A</div>
<div class="row" data-status="1">C</div>
<div class="row" data-status="0">B</div>
<div class="row" data-status="0">D</div>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they have a parent you can just (re)append them by using [**prepend()**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```js
$('.parent').prepend($('[data-status="1"]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row" data-status="1">A</div>
  <div class="row" data-status="0">B</div>
  <div class="row" data-status="1">C</div>
  <div class="row" data-status="0">D</div>
</div>
```

Note, this will not add new elements. Rather, it is implicitly resorting them due to appending the selected elements to the same div, but in the first position

Comment: Very cool solution - I think it's not so much that jq realizes you're re-appending to the same parent - but that append removes the parameter if the parameter is currently in the DOM

Comment: I didn't know it was possible this way, cool. Thanks for the one-line solution!

Comment: This is a great solution! It should get more upvotes really!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle it through a javascript method (instead of a CSS selector) then you could do something like the following:

```
$('.parent > div').sort(function (a, b) {

    var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-status'), 10);
    var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-status'), 10);
    return (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : 0;
}).appendTo('.parent');
```

```js
$('.parent div').sort(function (a, b) {

    var contentA = parseInt($(a).attr('data-status'), 10);
    var contentB = parseInt($(b).attr('data-status'), 10);
    return (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : 0;
}).appendTo('.parent');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="row" data-status="1">A</div>
    <div class="row" data-status="0">B</div>
    <div class="row" data-status="1">C</div>
    <div class="row" data-status="0">D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `detach()` and put it back with `prependTo` to have it stack on the top of the others

```
$("div[data-status=1]").detach().prependTo(".container");
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgjg05Lz/) slightly modified html